# Group by values across two columns and filter in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
    name    sex births  year
0   Mary    F   7433    2000
1   John    M   6542    2000
2   Emma    F   2342    2000
3   Ron     M   5432    2001
4   Bessie  F   4234    2001
5   Jennie  F   2413    2002
6   Nick    M   2343    2002
7   Ron     M   4342    2002
```

I need to get new DataFrame where data will be grouped by year and sex, and last two columns will be name with max births and max (births) value, like this:

```
    year   sex  name     births
0   2000   F    Mary     7433
1   2000   M    John     6542
2   2001   F    Bessie   4234
3   2001   M    Ron      5432   
4   2002   F    Jennie   2413
5   2002   M    Ron      4342
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done using the following `groupby` operation:

```
>>> df.groupby(['year', 'sex'], as_index=False).max()
   year sex    name  births
0  2000   F    Mary    7433
1  2000   M    John    6542
2  2001   F  Bessie    4234
3  2001   M     Ron    5432
4  2002   F  Jennie    2413
5  2002   M     Ron    4342
```

`as_index=False` stops the groupby keys from becoming the index in the returned DataFrame.

Alternatively, to get the desired output you may need to to sort the 'births' column and then use `groupby.first()`:

```
df = df.sort_values(by='births', ascending=False)
df.groupby(['year', 'sex'], as_index=False).first()
```

Comment: It work, but not always. For example if I change input row `6 Nick M 2343 2002` on `6 Nick M 12343 2002`, the output of your operation will be `5 2002 M Ron  12343`